# Firefox doesn't close WebSocket immediately on connection error?

Tags: javascript, firefox, websocket

I have this demo code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  </head>
    <body onload="init()">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {
            this.ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:1234");
            console.log("opening");

            // on close, display message and try to reopen
            this.ws.onclose = function (evt) {
                console.log("closed");
            }
        }
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which is connecting to a websocket endpoint that doesn't exist.  I would expect this to error out basically immediately, but in Firefox, the time between it printing "opening" and printing "closed" is over a minute:

[image: snippet]

Is this expected behavior, or can it be configured to time out more quickly?  In Chrome the connection errors out immediately:

[image: snippet]

Comment: I'm using Firefox 71.0 (64bit) and it writes the error/closes the connection immediately (same behavior in Chrome).. Running this on a Macbook Pro Catalina 10.15.2

Comment: Interesting, I'm Firefox 71 (64bit) on Linux Mint.  It's consistently taking > 60 seconds for me.

Comment: Markup note: this is superbad JS. You're writing modern HTML and JS: don't use _any_ `on...=` on HTML elements. (1) don't use `type="text/javascript" for script tags: you're using HTML5: `script` is Javascript by default. (2) make your JS an actual file, so that (3) you can use `<script src="..." defer></script>`. That'll load the source in parallel with everything else, but _run_ it only after the entire document's been parsed. And then put that `<script>` in the head element. Now that we have `async` and `defer`, don't put JS in your body anymore. Also: `<meta charset="utf-8">`. Again: HTML5

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for the valuable info but (1) how does that help here? (2) Pretty sure OP just provided that demo/example as the 'lowest denominator' type of code to be used for testing...

Comment: @gct which desktop are you using for Linux Mint? I can spin up a VM real quick to test..

Comment: @MattOestreich I'm using Cinnamon.  Interestingly, sometimes the connection _does_ close immediately.  Looking at Wireshark, I can see the SYN packet followed by a RST/ACK from the server.  If I reload after that, then it takes 60 seconds.  Is this some sort of SYN flood protection?

Comment: Now that I let it sit for a few minutes, it's closing the connection immediately...  If I do it too fast, then it starts backing off on the timeout, this must be some sort of protection to prevent DDOS.

Comment: Sounds like you're onto something -- I still haven't been able to reproduce, which is really odd.

Comment: I answered it below, it's an intentional change to try to comply with RFC 6455 better.

Comment: @gct comments are not answers. I left you a note on your markup, which is worth improving completely independently of your question. You're using HTML5, but you're also using HTML4.01 JS and HTML patterns. Stop using those patterns.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans  I appreciate it, but I'm not a webdev by day, so I just threw together minimal example.  I've used your bezier guide in the past, that's good stuff, thanks.

Comment: always glad to hear it's been useful - but even if you're not a web dev, showing modern code on SO is _always_ worth it. There's tons of boilerplates available for most common code editors (sublime, VS Code, etc) so typically you don't even want to write your own code. Just use "whatever's already guaranteed to be modern, proper code". (a `doctype html`, which explicitly says it's HTML5, but then a HTML4.01 meta tag syntax from literally over 20 years ago, for example, makes no sense =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. This is [intentional](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=711793) behavior to comply with RFC 6455.  Per [this](https://bug711793.bmoattachments.org/attachment.cgi?id=637655) patch, it uses an exponential backoff up to 60 seconds max.  Unfortunately I think this means auto-reconnecting to a websocket endpoint in Firefox is broken.